# Homomorphism $x^i \mapsto y^i$ and the order of $x$ and $y$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am trying to answer the following question:

> Let $G$ and $H$ be two cyclic groups generated by $x$ and $y$
>   respectively. Determine the condition on the orders $m$ and $n$ of $x$ and
>   $y$ so that the map $f(x^i)= y^i$ is a homomorphism.

How I attempted to solve the question in the following way:
Let $r$ and $s$ be two arbitrary integers. Then
$$f(x^rx^s) = f(x^{r+s})=y^{r+s}=y^ry^s=f(x^r)f(x^s)$$
Since we made no assumptions about the orders of $x$ and $y$, $f$ is an homomorphism from $G$ to $H$ no matter what the orders of $x$ and $y$ are.

I don't feel confident with my proof and I would love for someone to check it. Finally, I am aware there are some theorems about the order elements of a groups but I am supposed to solve the problem without them.

Comment: In order to show that $f$ is a homomorphism, you need to show that $f(x_1x_2)=f(x_1)f(x_2)$ for all $x_1, x_2\in G$, not just for $x_1, x_2$ equal to powers or some particular element of $G$.

Comment: But isn't it true that because $G=\langle x \rangle$ all the elements in $G$ are powers of a particular element of $G$ (namely $x$), and therefore proving $f(x^rx^s) = f(x^r)f(x^s)$ for arbitrary $r$ and $s$ is equivalent to prove it for that $f(x_1x_2)=f(x_1)f(x_2)$ for all $x_1,x_2 \in G$?

Comment: It’s not true that $G=\langle x\rangle$ for every $x\in G$. (In my first comment, I misspelled “of” as “or.”)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g_1, g_2 \in G$. We then have that $g_1=x^{k_1}$ and $g_2=x^{k_2}$ for $k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let $f$ be a homomorphism. Then
$$f(g_1g_2)=f(x^{k_1}x^{k_2})=f(x^{k_1+k_2})=f(g_1)f(g_2)=f(x^{k_1})(x^{k_2})=y^{k_1}y^{k_2}=y^{k_1+k_2}.$$

Further, recall that for any group homomorphism $\varphi: G \to H$ that for $g \in G$ we have that $|\varphi(g)|$ divides $|g|$.

Thus from above we must have that $|y^{k_1+k_2}|$ divides $|x^{k_1+k_2}|$. And since $G=\langle x \rangle$ and $H=\langle y \rangle$ with $|x|=m$ and $|y|=n$, it clearly follows that $G \cong \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ and $H \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore
$$|y^{k_1+k_2}|=\frac{n}{\gcd(k_1+k_2,n)},$$
$$|x^{k_1+k_2}|=\frac{m}{\gcd(k_1+k_2,m)}.$$
Using that the first expression divides the second, we have for $r \in \mathbb{Z}$
$$|x^{k_1+k_2}|=\frac{m}{\gcd(k_1+k_2,m)}=|y^{k_1+k_2}|\cdot r = \frac{nr}{\gcd(k_1+k_2,n)}$$
Providing us with
$$m=\frac{\gcd(k_1+k_2,m)}{\gcd(k_1+k_2,n)} \cdot nr$$